# Comparing it with Drupal 7: What are you most excited about in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-8

I read a good blog post on the importance of upgrading to Drupal 7 in preparation for Drupal 8. My site is already in Drupal 7 but in looking forward to Drupal 8, what makes the upgrade exciting?

Comment: I never asked the answer in a Yes/No 
All i want to know is the goodies and advantages of upgrading to Drupal 8 from the unstable Drupal 7. You don't seem to answer question in any possible proper way. So who's being unprofessional now. I even doubt you even familiar working with Drupal 8.

Willing to quote that again "My site is already in Drupal 7 but in looking forward to Drupal 8. WHAT MAKES The Upgrade Exciting?"

Comment: I have 2 sites online with Drupal 8. Please, read my answer again. I, also, say that it would be unprofessional if I say go or stop not that you are unprofessional.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a Yes/No answer here and if someone did that he would be an unprofessional.

In general everyone **may upgrade a CMS only if he needs more with the new version or if the old version does not meat the requirements anymore**. For example, if you need modules that don't exist on the old version or if you found out that the new version will do some important tasks better (eg be faster) then yes an upgrade would be a good practice.

On the other hand an upgrade will need time and working hours to be assigned and sometimes you may have to leave behind things that worked with a specific way on the old version. Even a new interface may cause problems.

So, to conclude, an upgrade is not a so easy task, it is like buying a new car. Does the old car do the job or not? Does the new car worth its money?

Comment: I never asked the answer in a Yes/No 
All i want to know is the goodies and advantages of upgrading to Drupal 8. 

Willing to quote that again "My site is already in Drupal 7 but in looking forward to Drupal 8. WHAT MAKES The Upgrade Exciting?"

Comment: I did not answer a Yes/No question but a question that needs an answer without providing details... In any case I think I made it clear what are the major issues when someone decides or not to do an upgrade.

Comment: Your answer is still not satisfying.
thank you! Well I got the answer anyway